# How to separate number and unit from variable when using awk

Tags: linux, awk

In a 10 line awk script I need to split the content of a variable into a number variable and an unit variable. Here is a simplified example

```
~$ echo 139506MB | awk '{
   ex = index("KMGTPEZY", substr($1, length($1)));
   val = substr($1, 0, length($1) - 2);
   print ex " " val
   }'
0 139506
```

I know the unit part is always 2 chars, but for some reason `ex` always returns `0` instead of `MB` as I was hoping.

**Question**

Any idea why `ex` doesn't contain the unit?

Comment: @Sandra, if you could do let us know complete requirement of your question then we could help you more on same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The logic in your `index()` function is wrong, the character you've extracted is not part of the string you've defined. Hence the return value 0 you are seeing.

For a regex approach using GNU Awk for storing captured groups to an array. With the `match()` function you could do as below. The captured groups are stored into the array(`ar`) from which you can access the elements 1 and 2.

```
echo 139506MB | gawk 'match($0, /([[:digit:]]+)([[:alpha:]]+)/, ary) {print ary[1] ary[2]}'
```

Answer (score 2):

Using GNU awk and `split`'s *seps* to abuse the `.B` as the separator *to separate number and unit from variable when using* (GNU) *awk*:

```
$ echo 139506MB  | awk '{split($1,a,/.B/,seps);print seps[1],a[1]}'
MB 139506
```

Also, regarding your code: You (try to) set the `index` of `M` in string `KMGTPEZY` so I assume you are looking for `ex==2`. By fixing the `substr` like below:

```
$ echo 139506MB | awk '{
   ex = index("KMGTPEZY", substr($1, length($1)-1,1));    # from substr($1, length($1))
   # ex = substr($1, length($1)-1,1);                     # uncomment for the unit
   val = substr($1, 0, length($1) - 2);
   print ex " " val
   }'
2 139506
```

Maybe you should update the OP with the expected output.

Answer (score 2):

Your `substr()` call is `substr($1, length($1))` which will return only the last character of `$1` (`B`).  This character is not part of the string `KMGTPEZY`.

```
$ echo '139506MB' | awk '{ n=$1+0; sub(n,"",$1); print $1,n }'
MB 139506
```

This uses the fact that converting a string to a number discards everything from the first non-digit.  This allows us to store the number in `n` using `$1+0` (force interpreting the first field as a number).  We then remove the number from the original line using `sub()`.  The number and the remaining text is then printed.

Answer (score 1):

The first issue is here:

```
substr($1, length($1))
```

You are getting the last character of the string, which is "B". There is no "B" in "KMGTPEZY", so `index` returns `0`.

I don't think you need to use `index` at all. To use `substr`:

```
ex = substr($1, length($1) - 1);
val = substr($1, 0, length($1) - 2);
```

Testing:

```
$ awk '{ print substr($1, length($1) - 1), substr($1, 0, length($0) - 2) }' <<< '139506MB'
MB 139506
```

Comment: In your code `ex` returns empty` and `val` returns `139506MB`.

Comment: `awk '{ print substr($1, length($1) - 1), substr($0, 0, length($0) - 2) }' <<< '139506MB'` produces `MB 139506`.

Answer (score 1):

Following `awk` may help you on same too.

```
str="139506MB"
echo "$str" | awk '
match($0,/[0-9]+/){
  val=substr($0,RSTART+RLENGTH);
  if(val ~ /[a-zA-Z]+/){
     print substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH),val}
}'
```